# numpy slicing using multiple conditions where one of the conditions searches the neighborhood of an element

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, opencv, image-processing

the problem is to take a black-white image, detect all the places where white borders on black, keep that white, and turn all other white pixels black. I know how to do this using normal for-loops and lists, but I want to do it w/ numpy, which I am not that familiar with. Here is what I have so far:

```
>>>from PIL Import Image
>>>import numpy as np

>>>a = Image.open('a.png')
>>>a = a.convert('L')
>>>a_np = np.array(a)

>>>a_np

array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       ...,
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)

>>>mask = np.pad(a_np[1:-1,1:-1],1,mode='wrap') != 0
>>>mask
array([[False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
       ...,
       [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False]])
>>> np.where(mask == True)
(array([ 98,  98,  98, ..., 981, 981, 981]), array([393, 394, 395, ..., 684, 685, 686]))
>>> a_np[mask] = 0
>>> a_np
array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       ...,
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)
>>> np.where(a_np == 1)
(array([], dtype=int64), array([], dtype=int64))
```

Basically, trying to create a mask that finds the neighbors of every element in the array and for those that do not have a black neighbor, turn them black - but no matter what I try I either get all black elements or the same array that I started with. Numpy or OpenCV solutions are welcome.

BEFORE
[image]

AFTER
[image]

Comment: Have you ever tried opencv? This is typically the kind of things it can handle at a higher level. You could add the opencv tag and also welcome opencv solutions.

Comment: Can you also provide a toy image? (and if possible the matching expected output image)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) and help of [scipy](/questions/tagged/scipy), this can be achieved with a [`binary_erosion`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.binary_erosion.html).

One can erode the pixels with a kernel of 3x3, then compare the original image to the erosion to find the difference:

```
from scipy.ndimage import binary_erosion

kernel = np.ones((3,3))

edges = a_np - binary_erosion(a_np, kernel)*255

out = Image.fromarray(edges.astype('uint8'), 'L')
```

output image:

[image: contour]

Comment: perfect, thank you - I figured there would be a short and elegant solution.

Comment: There might be a shorter way with image libraries, like edge detection but I don't use those enough to remember ;)

Comment: You can use pillow img.filter(ImageFilter.MinFilter(3)) as erosion operation.